# Cannot convert java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Good Afternoon I have an issue with conversation of trying to find value from an api call which is

```
        requestResponse.value = "Raw response:\n\n${response.body().toString()} \n\n${(JSONObject(response.body().toString()).**getJSONObject("value").toString()**)}"
```

The error stack I get is

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.retrofittest, PID: 17673
    org.json.JSONException: Value Chuck Norris found Waldo, Carmen Sandiego and Jimmy Hoffa. at value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
        at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONObject(JSONObject.java:613)
        at com.example.retrofittest.ui.main.PageViewModel$executeRequest$1.invokeSuspend(PageViewModel.kt:56)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

why is the getJSONObject("value").toString() convertion having this issue?

Many Thanks

Comment: try using `getString("value")` instead of `getJSONObject("value").toString()`. because `value` seems to be a normal string, not a JSON object.

Comment: Put your resposne.body().to string data in your question